# C# - LINQ Query for this purpose

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-5

I have the following classes with these fields

```
public class Account {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Username { get; set; }
     public float Timezone { get; set; }
}

public class Player {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
     public string Team_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose I have a List<> of Player called Players, each team has 2 players, that means every Team_Name will be repeated twice. E.g. Team X has Player A and Player B, two entries in the List<> of Player to represent that.

What I want to achieve is pair teams against each other based on timezone, since each team has 2 players I should calculate the average timezone for each team by accessing Account.Timezone field in Player class, then find another team with closest average timezone to match the team against them.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU3rE.png)

Comment: For output I just want a sorted list<> of Player, it will be index [0] team vs index [1] in the list and so on... there should be no duplicate entry of team_name in output

Comment: Is there a reason to not have a `Team` class that contains players instead?

Comment: Yes because actually there is a 3rd class called Tournaments, Player class is just there to do the many to many relationship between Accounts and Tournaments, I didn't include it because its not needed to solve, also more fields for both classes above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GroupBy() to group your `List<Player>` by Team_Name and go from there.

However, my preference would be to create a new entity Team and give that entity either Player1 and Player2 properties, or a `List<Player> Players` property. I would then have a getter TeamTimezone that calculates the average timezone of the players on the team.

Adding a class to represent the concept of Team more clearly expresses what your program is doing, making it more understandable and reduces the chances of bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a `Match` class like this:

```
public class Match
{
    public string Team1 { get; set; }
    public string Team2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can do something like this with LINQ:

```
var matches =
    Players.GroupBy(player => player.Team_Name) //Group players by team name
        .Select(
            team => //For each team
                new
                {
                    TeamName = team.Key, //Select team name
                    AverageTimezone = //And average time zone
                        team.Average(player => player.Account.Timezone)
                })
        .OrderBy(team => team.AverageTimezone) //Order teams by average time zone
        .Select((team, index) => new {Team = team, Index = index})
        .GroupBy(item => item.Index/2) //Group each two teams together (since the teams are ordered by average timezone, each two teams will have a close timezone)
        .Select(g => g.Select(item => item.Team).ToList())
        .Select(g => new Match
        {
            Team1 = g[0].TeamName,
            Team2 = g[1].TeamName
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: The average can just be `team.Average(player => player.Account.Timezone)`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what would happen if the list<> of Players has an odd number of entries

Comment: @HappySylveon, but you said in the question that `each team has 2 players, that means every Team_Name will be repeated twice`.